# How can I hide the number of new apps on the "All Apps" icon of the start menu?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

Can the number 3 in the image be hidden?

[image]

Comment: Not so far as I know .  As you action / test recently apps, the number disappears.

Comment: Go to Windows Settings (right click on the W10 flag and select settings), click Personalization, then "Start" on left side, turn off "show recently added apps", see if this does it.

Comment: @moab it doesn't.